# Monolithic or SOA sample application for transformation to microservices

Tags: c#, .net, microservices, soa, sample

For a project at university I am looking for sample applications in the .NET environment that are designed as a Monolith or as a Service Oriented Architecture. I want to take this sample application and use several approaches to transform this into a microservices architecture, but unfortunately I have problems finding samples bigger than a simple Hello-World application.

A bonus would be if the application uses REST for backend services, maybe ASP.NET Web API.

Maybe somebody could point me to some existing samples. 
I am not sure if this belongs to Stack Overflow but I could not find any better fitting Stack Exchange community.

Comment: search for "c# sample mvc tutorial" in google, there are many, classic MVC projects are perfect for such an exercise

Comment: Unfortunately the projects I can find are too small to do a reasonable transformation to microservices.